# When $f' \in k[f,g]$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, $f=f(t), g=g(t) \in k[t]$, $\deg(f)=n, \deg(g)=m$.

Assume that $n \geq 2, m \geq 2$ and $k(f,g)=k(t)$.

> (1) Can one tell when $f'=f'(t) \in k[f,g]$?

Trivially, if $k[f,g]=k[t]$ then of course $f' \in k[f,g]$, but we do not know whether $k[f,g]=k[t]$ or not (we do know that $k(f,g)=k(t)$, but I am not sure how this helps).

> (2) It would be nice to see an example where $f' \in k[f,g]$ but $g' \notin k[f,g]$.

Any comments are welcome!

**Edit:** Perhaps the following arguments may help: Write $t=\frac{u}{v}$, where $u,v \in k[f,g]$. Write $f=\sum_{0}^{n} a_it^i$, $g=\sum_{0}^{m} b_jt^j$, $a_i,b_j \in k$. Then $f'=\sum_{1}^{n} ia_it^{i-1}=\sum_{1}^{n} ia_i(\frac{u}{v})^{i-1}=\frac{w}{v^{n-1}}$, where $w \in k[u,v]$. (Then $v^{n-1}f'=w \in k[u,v] \subseteq k[f,g]$). Consider the localization $S^{-1}k[f,g]$, where $S=\{v^i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}.$ We have just obtained that $f' \in S^{-1}k[f,g]$.
Notice that $t \in S^{-1}k[f,g]$ (since $t=\frac{u}{v}$). Therefore, $S^{-1}k[f,g]=S^{-1}k[t]$ is a UFD (a localization of a UFD is a UFD). If $S$ is primal then $k[f,g]$ is a UFD by [Nagata's criterion](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral2015.pdf) (Theorem 15.41). However, we do not know if $S$ is primal or not.

Comment: I would try with $g(t)=tf(t)$ and a suitably chosen $f$.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please elaborate? Did you mean that such $f$ and $g$ may yield an answer to $(2)$? What about question $(1)$?.

Comment: I'm not sure at all that it works, it is just an idea. The idea is that with this choice, you are certain that $k(f,g)=k(t)$. So all you need is to choose $f$ so that $f'\not\in k[f,g]$.

Comment: $f=t^3,g=t^2$  answers $(2)$?

Comment: Ah nice, yes it looks so.

Comment: Thanks (it's the simplest example I could think about). Concerning your idea: Nice; can one tell for which $f$ and $g$ such that $g=tf$, both $f'$ and $g'$ belong to $k[f,g]$?